# Drupal search with link to node

Tags: drupal, search, module

I have drupal installed on my site, and I have the search module enabled. However, when I ever I search for key terms it displays the node with the keywords but there is no link to the node(s) that returned.

How do I provide a link with the returned results? I want them to be able to search for a node then click on the results to view that particular node, but I can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`search-result.tpl.php` Default theme implementation for displaying a single search result.